# how to export gridview to pdf in c#

Tags: c#

Can anybody please tell me how to export data from gridview to pdf in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is `no build in class in .Net`

hope these links can help you

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/12/export-gridview-to-pdf-using-itextsharp.html

http://forums.asp.net/t/1412788.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot... but isnt there any way to do so without using any third party code?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this free library [ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into the base class library of .NET that allows you to generate PDF files. You might need to use a third party library such as [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Crystal Reports. It won't allow you to export a gridview directly but you can extract and display the same data.

Answer (score 0):

You must add this reference of (iTextSharp)..

```
  public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }
    protected void GeneratePDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
        GridView1.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
        GridView1.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
        GridView1.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();   
   }
```